# How would I hide the action button until all selections are made?

Tags: r, shiny

I was wondering if there was a way to hide the action button on my shiny app until after the variable selections are displayed in the side panel. I have been having trouble achieving this with a uiOutput for the button as it confuses the dataTable, as it thinks that input$submit is an empty value. Here is the code so far:

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("CSV Viewer"),

  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput('file1', 'CSV File',
              accept=c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', '.csv')),


    tags$hr(),

    checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),

    radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                 c(Comma=',',
                   Semicolon=';',
                   Tab='\t'),
                 'Comma'),

    uiOutput('varselect'),

    actionButton('submit', 'Submit')

  ),

  mainPanel(

    dataTableOutput('contents')

  )
))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  observe({
    csvfile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(csvfile))
      {return(NULL)}

    dt <- read.csv(csvfile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep,   quote=input$quote)

    output$varselect <- renderUI({

      checkboxGroupInput("var", "Variables", choices = names(dt), select = names(dt))

    })

    if (input$submit > 0) {output$contents <- renderDataTable({

       isolate(dt[ ,input$var])

    })} 
  })
})
```

tl;dr I want to prevent a user from pushing the "Submit" button before they select a file to upload. This is proving to be difficult for me.

Thanks in advance for all of your help! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the `actionButton` to your `renderUI`. I also tidied up your `server.R` as everything was wrapped in an `observe` which would probably not be best going forward.

```
library(shiny)

runApp(list(
  ui = pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("CSV Viewer"),

    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file1', 'CSV File',
                accept=c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', '.csv')),


      tags$hr(),

      checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),

      radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                   c(Comma=',',
                     Semicolon=';',
                     Tab='\t'),
                   'Comma'),

      uiOutput('varselect')
    ),

    mainPanel(

      dataTableOutput('contents')

    )
  )
  ,server = function(input, output, session) {


    csvfile <- reactive({
      csvfile <- input$file1
      if (is.null(csvfile)){return(NULL)}
      dt <- read.csv(csvfile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep,   quote=input$quote)
      dt
    })

    output$varselect <- renderUI({
      if(is.null(input$file1$datapath)){return()}
      list(
        checkboxGroupInput("var", "Variables", choices = names(csvfile()), select = names(csvfile()))
        , actionButton('submit', 'Submit')
      )
    })

    output$contents <- renderDataTable({
      if(is.null(input$file1$datapath)){return()}
      if(input$submit > 0){
        isolate(csvfile()[ ,input$var])
      }
    })

  } 

)
)
```